# New profile pages -- I can't find my "days visited"

Tags: support

I don't seem to be able to find my statisticas previously described as

`Days visited: x (y consecutive)`

Can anyone tell me where it's gone (and preferably not to BitValhalla!)?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Brent, it took me a while, but I found it! Here it is:

1. In your user page, make sure the *Profile* tab is selected.

   [image: Quack 1]
2. Then, in the right side of the screen, near your description, you will find the following box:

   [image: Quack 2]

   The last item in the list (visible only for you) contains the <s>droid</s> info you are looking for (sadly, the fact the word *consecutive* is truncated is driving me insane!). If you click it, a calendar will appear:

   [image: Quack 3]

   The days coloured in green mean the days you visited the site.

The new profile page is surely confusing. `:)`

Comment: 1454 days consecutively? A very busy duck ;-)

Comment: @ChristianHupfer Quack! `:)`

Comment: Thanks, Paulo. I'm not very good at Zork, either...